# Questionnaire scoring based on User's score

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, calculator, rating

I'm a total noob so pardon the errors. I am trying to create a script that returns a new score for User B based on User A's score depending on the results of a 5-point Likert scale questionnaire. Both are firstly inputs at the top of the page, then the questionnaire which changes User B's score is below. It should work like this:
Firstly: 
User A Score = x
 User B score = y
It rounds User A's score to the nearest 50, then divides it by 50 to create a number we'll call z.
E.g User A score = 442, it gets rounded to 450, then divided by 50 = 9.This new number is z. or z =x/50 (to the nearest whole number). Now based on the survey responses, if User A clicks "very poor", it takes the input data for User B's score and subtracts z from it. Then gives a new result below based on the result of the questionnaire after submission such that:
Very poor = y-z
Poor = y (doesn't change the score)
Satisfactory = y+z
Good = y+z+1
Very good = y+z+2
Let me know if this makes sense. I attached a sample code I tried making below but I'm sure it's wrong. It needs to do more than this but this is the bare minimum I want to figure out. Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>
        Questionnaire mess around
    </h1>
    <p>

        <label for='ascore' class="inlinelabel">User A Score</label>
        <input id="ascore" type="number"> <br>
        <br>
        <label for='bscore' class="inlinelabel">User B Score</label>
        <input id="bscore" type="number">

        </p>


    <form action="" id="scorecalc" onsubmit="return false;">
       <fieldset>


        <br>
        <legend>Peer Review Questionnaire!</legend>
        <h3> Based on your recent project together, how would you rate User B in the following Skills</h3>

            <hr>
        <label ><strong>Time Management</strong></label> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmvpoor" />
        Very Poor
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmpoor"/>
        Poor
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmsat" />
        Satisfactory
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmgood"/>
        Good
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmvgood" />
        Very Good

        <br>

       <button onclick="myFunction()" class="button">Submit</button>


        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <h2>

    User B New Score </h2>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <script> 
    var theForm = document.forms["scorecalc"];
    var x = document.getElementByID(ascore).value
    var y = document.getElementByID(bscore).value

    function closest50(x) {
      return Math.round(x/ 50) * 50
    }

    var z = closest50(x)

    var tm_result = new Array();
    tm_result["tmvpoor"]=y-z;
    tm_result["tmpoor"]=y;
    tm_result["tmsat"]=y+z;
    tm_result["tmgood"]=y+z+1;
    tm_result["tmvgood"]=y+z+2

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tm_result;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of problems in your code

- things that should be inside of function are not

  you don't really want an array but object to store key/value pairs

  value of input fields is always string, you need to convert it to number before doing mathematical operations with it

  document.getElementByID is not a function you want ...ById

  you have said that you want to divide x by 50 but you immediately multiply it by 50 back to the original

  ascore and bscore in your document.getElementById should be strings

  you want to pass string to .innerHTML not an array/object

Here is working code. If you have some questions about it, post a comment below (I have changed only the JS part).

```js
const theForm = document.querySelector('#scorecalc');

function closest50(x) {
 return Math.round(x / 50);
}

function myFunction() {
   const x = Number(document.getElementById('ascore').value);
   const y = Number(document.getElementById('bscore').value);
   const choice = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').value;
   const z = closest50(x)

   const tm_result = {
     tmvpoor: y - z,
     tmpoor: y,
     tmsat: y + z,
     tmgood: y + z + 1,
     tmvgood: y + z + 2
   };

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tm_result[choice];
}
```

```html
    <h1>
        Questionnaire mess around
    </h1>
    <p>

        <label for='ascore' class="inlinelabel">User A Score</label>
        <input id="ascore" type="number"> <br>
        <br>
        <label for='bscore' class="inlinelabel">User B Score</label>
        <input id="bscore" type="number">

        </p>


    <form action="" id="scorecalc" onsubmit="return false;">
       <fieldset>


        <br>
        <legend>Peer Review Questionnaire!</legend>
        <h3> Based on your recent project together, how would you rate User B in the following Skills</h3>

            <hr>
        <label ><strong>Time Management</strong></label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmvpoor" />
        Very Poor
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmpoor"/>
        Poor
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmsat" />
        Satisfactory
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmgood"/>
        Good
        <input type="radio"  name="tmscore" value="tmvgood" />
        Very Good

        <br>

       <button onclick="myFunction()" class="button">Submit</button>


        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <h2>User B New Score </h2>

    <p id="result"></p>
```